# Downgrading Virtualbox, conflicting packages

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, dpkg, downgrade

I'm trying to downgrade VirtualBox to `5.0.26` because I have sound issues with Genymotion and I hope they get fixed.

I currently have `5.1.14`. I got the .deb for 5.0.26 from [their archive here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.26/). I try to do `sudo dpkg -i '/path/to/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.26-108824-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb'` I get

```
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-5.0.
dpkg: regarding .../virtualbox-5.0_5.0.26-108824-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb containing virtualbox-5.0:
 virtualbox-5.0 conflicts with virtualbox
  virtualbox-5.1 provides virtualbox and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /path/to/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.26-108824-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing virtualbox-5.0
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /path/to/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.26-108824-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb
```

I also *tried to try* to install it from the repos directly via apt but I can't get the command right. Tried `sudo apt install virtualbox=50.026` -> `E: Version '50.026' for 'virtualbox' was not found`

Comment: I had to downgrade virtualbox when they broke restoring snapshots (It's fixed now and I had to re-upgrade).  I completely removed the existing virtualbox install, and then completely reinstalled the version I wanted.  You may have done this, but you did not mention removing the old version.  I also downloaded from here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0 not the page you linked (although it may be the same link in the end)

Comment: okay so I'm thinking I'd do `apt purge` on virtualbox then try install from the .deb but I don't want it to remove the current machines. Did your deployed machines survive the downgrade? @OrganicMarble thx

Comment: Yes, but I am paranoid so I backed them up first.

Comment: backing up is never a paranoia!! cheers :) @OrganicMarble

Comment: Before downgrading (which usually does not fix things but re-introduces long fixed bugs) I'd try an upgrade to the most recent version (presently 5.1.16).

Comment: I'm usually up-to-date. This issue's been around for a while. Someone (probably from Genymotion) instructed me to downgrade to that specific version. thx @Takkat

Comment: Was it reported as a bug to the VirtualBox people (otherwise it is not going to be fixed any time)?

Comment: no I don't think so afaik, but it might be a bug with Genymotion in the first place and I did report that @Takkat